# I have disable the Gradles offline mode , and now there is a new error as below :

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.3/gradle-4.1.3.jar'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0fOA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do not have gradle offline mode enabled. Your gradle toolbar should look like the one below. The 4 icon from the left, is the toggle offline/online button. It should not be selected.

[image: gradle toggle offline/online]

You can run the actions like the following to do a gradle sync with your project.

[image: gradle sync action]

That should get you back online and your project synced up.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue with my Android Studio. This is happening due to a bad link in moven, In my case, I  was using the given link which is not reachable now and giving 502 error.

```
  maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
        }
```

Solution:- I have commented on my maven link and Sync my Gradle now it's working.

```
// maven {
//        url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
//    }
```

Explanation: if you are using any such link in your `build.gradle` then try to rectify from error. Comment your block of code and resync.